# Grant one process access to proc of another process?

Tags: linux, proc, ptrace

I'd like a monitoring daemon to be able to access `/proc/<PID>/smaps_rollup` of another process to be able to report swap usage of that process.

I found information that access to that file is "governed by a ptrace access mode `PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS` check" but I have no idea what that means.

Is there a way to grant the monitoring daemon access to the `smaps_rollup` file of another process, other than running it as root?

Comment: Running the monitoring process as the same UID as the target process would probably do it.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' It's more than one target with different users unfortunately.